# Create pop up with user password as dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I'm using the following code in MVC5 view index.cshtml. Currently the alert shows some text. I need to change it to open a pop-up asking user for a *username* and a *password*, how should I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function () { 
     $("#M").change(function () { 
     if ($(this).val() == "F") { 
             alert("I am an alert box!");

       } 
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

I've tried `var myWindow = window.showPopup();` which is not working ...

Answer (score 1):

```
var username = window.prompt("Enter your username","");
var password = window.prompt("Enter your password","");
```

Access what the username and password the user had typed in with the variables `username` and `password`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/yT9sg/). Hope that was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks Chris voted up, I have two question 1. I want the user password will be and the same popup ,how should I change it 2. how can I apply some style to this popup ...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You could use jquery dialogs or create a separate form for the username and password.

Comment: Then what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap and use the component [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). The bootstrap site offers a nice tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks but how should I call it from the script ?can you please provide example?

Comment: If you read the link that I gave you can easily show the popup(modal) by: $('#myModal').modal('show')